# Variation of Paramters: method confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation be$$y''+4y'+4y=t^{-2}e^{-2t} ~;\;~~~ t>0  $$

I already solved this question myself but the textbook states that I am incorrect. I am honestly starting to think that there might be an error in the written solutions. I was wondering if anybody could solve this problem and show me what they have gotten for a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. To help us give an answer which best helps you, such as possibly determining what you or the textbook got wrong, please update your question with at least the solution you got and what the textbook says it should be instead.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Plug your answer and take the derivatives. If you got it right, then you will get $0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''+4y'+4y=t^{-2}e^{-2t} ;\; t>0  \tag 6$$
$$(y''+2y')+(2y'+4y)=t^{-2}e^{-2t}$$
$$(y'+2y)'+2(y'+2y)=t^{-2}e^{-2t}$$
$$(y'+2y)'e^{2t}+2e^{2t}(y'+2y)=t^{-2}$$
$$((y'+2y)e^{2t})'=t^{-2}$$
$$(ye^{2t})''=t^{-2}$$
Integrate twice.
$$(ye^{2t})'=-t^{-1}+C_1$$
Finally:
$$ \boxed {y(t)=(-\ln ( t)+C_1 t+C_2)e^{-2t}}$$

Comment: The absolute value is not needed seeing as the problem specifies $t>0$.

Comment: I know its just a habit I have. i noticed that. I will rewrite it. Thanks @Math1000

Answer (score 1):

First find the general solution to the associated homogeneous ODE; the characteristic polynomial is $r^2+4r+4$ which has root $r=-2$ with multiplicity $2$. Hence the general solution to $y''+4y'+4y=0$ is $y_c(t)=c_1e^{-2t}+c_2te^{-2t}$; we have two linearly independent solutions $y_1(t) = e^{-2t}$ and $y_2(t) = te^{-2t}$. Now compute the Wronskian:
\begin{align}
W(y_1,y_2) &= \begin{vmatrix}
y_1(t) & y_2(t)\\
y_1'(t) & y_2'(t)
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=\begin{vmatrix}
e^{-2t} & te^{-2t}\\
-2e^{-2t} & (1-2t)e^{-2t}
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= (1-2t)e^{-4t} + 2te^{-4t}\\
&= e^{-4t}.
\end{align}
The variation of parameters method yields this particular solution to the nonhomogeneous ODE:
\begin{align}
y_p(t) &= -y_1(t)\int\frac{y_2(t)t^{-2}e^{-2t}}{e^{-4t}}\ \mathsf dt + y_2(t)\int\frac{y_1(t)t^{-2}e^{-2t}}{e^{-4t}}\ \mathsf dt\\
&= -e^{-2t}\int t^{-1}\ \mathsf dt + te^{-2t}\int t^{-2}\ \mathsf dt\\
&= -e^{-2t}\log t - e^{-2t}\\
&= -e^{-2t}(1+\log t).
\end{align}
Therefore the general solution is given by
$$
y(t) = y_c(t) + y_p(t) = e^{-2t}(c_1 + c_2t - \log t).$$

Comment: @LostInSpace True, I will revise the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it simpler
$$y=z\,e^{-2t} \implies z''=\frac 1 {t^2}\implies z'=-\frac 1t+c_1\implies z=-\log(t)+c_1t+c_2$$ $$\implies y=e^{-2t}\left(-\log(t)+c_1t+c_2 \right)$$